MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=65535, message=maximum vector field's number should be limited to 4)>
I am getting the following error while I am creating 5 different vector field in milvusdb.
MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=65535, message=maximum vector field's number should be limited to 4)>

Just in case I asked this question. I think the reason is milvus db is supporting maximum 4 vector field in the db. But any case, I want to ask this question.
how can I increase the field size more than 4 in milvus db for vector fields??

https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/blob/a5d1135512b42f702a2eba29fb79be8377d0bfe1/configs/milvus.yaml#L209
You can config the number of the max vector field
If you install Milvus by the helm, you can follow this doc: https://milvus.io/docs/configure-helm.md

Multiple vector fields (up to 10) per collection are supported since Milvus >= version 2.4.  Older versions of Milvus will only support a single vector index at a time.
https://milvus.io/docs/multi-vector-search.md
